# Make capistrano revision file publicly web accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Capistrano leaves a file called REVISION in the current directory (this is for Rails but the question applies to any Capistrano deployment).  Is there a plugin or a task that anyone has written to automate making the revision file public?  The goal is to keep track of all of our servers version so we can manage deploys.

Comment: Symlink it into the `public` folder?

Comment: by saying keep track do you mea you want to save esch REVISION's content to DB?

Comment: i'd like to be able to go to a browser, go to the box, and see the REVISION file in a url.  I don't mind if it's public.  So a task after deploy to symlink REVISION to public would work fine but i can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: @seethrough or if there is a db solution, i'd be interested in that too, but the quick and dirty solution of linking it to the the public directory would work for now.